# How to use Razor syntax in kendo ui grid template

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-template

in kendo grid i want to display a link with condition,
i have a model field with bool type and there if value is true then that link need to be display otherwise display none.

now i have a @T("Admin.Common.Publish")

but it's not working in kendo grid 
can any one suggest me how to use this in kendo grid template?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample here? It would make it easier to work out what you are after :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have try to use this and it's work

"link"

if IsReady is true then this link is show other wise it's hide.

Regards,
vinit